# vlookup comparing value from 1 cell with values in 3 other columns - Need to output value of correct match

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have an excel spreadsheet. I need to check if the value in a cell in column A is present in any cell in columns B, C and D.

Here is my current formula:
=AND( NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,$B:$B,1,FALSE))), NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,$C:$C,1,FALSE))), NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,$D:$D,1,FALSE))) )

This formula works, in that if the value in A2 is present in a cell in column B, C, and D it will return true - It returns false if not.

What I'm looking to do is to return the value in A2 when the match is correct.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To solely answer your question, you can just put this around your formula:

```
= IF(<your formula>,A2)
```

This returns whatever is in cell `A2` if your formula evaluates to `TRUE`, and returns `FALSE` otherwise.

---

**More Info, Suggest you Read**

You're not really using `VLOOKUP` for it's intended purpose. `VLOOKUP` is used when you want to find a match in a table, then return some other value in the table with the same vertical index.

Since you just want to determine if a certain value is in a range or not, `VLOOKUP` is overkill.

Instead of `VLOOKUP` inside the `IF` statement, you should just do this:

```
= IF(AND(COUNTIF($B:$B,A2),COUNTIF($C:$C,A2),COUNTIF($D:$D,A2)),A2)
```

This should return the same result but is shorter and more efficient.